# Little exercise in analytic number theory

Tags: analytic-number-theory

I've found this exercise in a book, it's the following: "Show that for $x\geq 1$, for all $n\leq x$ except $o(x)$, the function $\Omega(n)$, which counts the number of prime divisors of $n$ with their multeplicity, is $(1+o(1))\log\log n$". How can I start? Thanks!

Comment: You could start by seeing whether it's in Hardy and Wright.

Comment: the Hardy-Turan theorem gives a similar asymptotic formula for $\omega(n)$, but it's in terms of big oh, my problem is to use small oh, and I'd like to use this formula, but I need to find a relationship between $\Omega$ and $\omega$...

Comment: Any reaction to my answer, Lyndon?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hardy and Wright, An Introduction to the Theory of Numbers, 6th edition, Theorem 431 states that the number of $n$ not exceeding $x$ for which $$|\Omega(n)-\log\log n|>(\log\log n)^{.5+\delta}$$ is $o(x)$ for every positive $\delta$. I'm not going to write out the proof, as it's lengthy. The footnotes on page 498 are also quite informative.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I'm reading Hardy and Wright and It is clearing me a lot of things and doubts...

Comment: Welcome back. If you found my answer helpful, you have the option of "accepting" it by clicking in the check mark next to it.